# Getting error with forecast library in R, what to do? I have re-installed the library but this error keeps coming

Tags: r, forecast, r-library

> library(forecast)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 4.0.3

Comment: As the error says, you need to update `rlang`

Comment: rlang makes victims everyday

Comment: install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_0.2.2.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source") use this link to update rlang still the error retains.